# Grails async - creating promises

Tags: grails, asynchronous

I am in grails 2.3.1 - trying to use the [async features](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/async.html).

This is bulk data processing. I am trying to synchronise 2 databases, which involves comparing both and returning a list of 'deltas'. I am trying to speed up the process

The documentation says I can just add a set of closures to a PromiseList and then call onComplete() to check that all the closures have completed. These are my attempts - directly building on "You can also construct a PromiseList manually" in the documentation:

```
    def tasksMemberDeltas = new PromiseList()
    pages.each {Integer page ->
        tasksMemberDeltas << {findCreateMemberDeltas(page, (page + pageSize) - 1)}
        if (page % 30 == 0) {
            tasksMemberDeltas.onComplete {
                tasksMemberDeltas = new PromiseList()
            }
        }
```

Returns:

```
Error groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
 No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.onComplete()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I called .get() which calls waitAll. Going into .get() and finding that it did waitAll was my revelation.

So if I have a single task I call:

```
waitAll finalDeltas
```

If I have a list I call:

```
taskFinalDeltas.get()
```

onComplete() logically relates to a single delta. Not the list. So this works OK:

```
Promise memberDeleteDeltas = task {
        findDeleteAndTagDeltas()
    }
    memberDeleteDeltas.onError { Throwable err ->
        println "An error occured ${err.message}"
    }
    memberDeleteDeltas.onComplete { result ->
        println "Completed create deltas"
    }
    waitAll(memberDeleteDeltas)
```